# twig template engine's form_widget

Tags: php, template-engine, twig

I am currently updating a PHP application so that it uses the very nice [twig template engine](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

I have hit a snag as to how to approach this issue. The application has their own set of custom developed form classes. Essentially, one can progammatically add fields, set methods and actions to the form object. Once this is all done, a the `render()` method is called, which then spits out a generated HTML snippet for the form.

I was able to output the form in a template using the `raw` filter like so:

```
{{ form|raw }}
```

While this works well, I notice that symfony2 has a method called [form_widget()](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) which specifically deals with rendering forms without having to output as raw.

I would like to adapt the application so that I can use `form_widget()`, however, I am unable to find any indepth documentation on it. Can anyone point out how data should be passed to `form_widget()` without using the symphony2 framework? Whether it is an array, object, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the trawling through Symphony's source code, it looks like all they have done is created an extension so that forms will be rendered as HTML:

```
'form_widget' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'renderWidget', array('is_safe' => array('html'))),
```

So, I guess all I need to do is create my own twig extension to provide similiar functionality.